# How to view drupal 7 sessions from an external PHP page?

Tags: session, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, session-variables

I installed drupal 7 and I need to include a block of PHP code in the user profile page.

I created a new block and I put this code in it:

```
"include (http://mysite/sites/all/themes/campi_aggiuntivi.php)"
```

In "campi_aggiuntivi.php" I put the following code:

```
session_start ();
print_r ($ _SESSION);
```

But it returns an empty array.

How do I interact with drupal sessions in this external page?

Thank you very much for your answares.

---

Thank you all for your answers.
I'm trying to install a module and insert it into a block avege as I suggested.

I created the file test.info

```
name = Test Block
description = description Test Block
package = package Test Block
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = block

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2013-02-01
version = "7.x-1.x-dev"
core = "7.x"
project = "Test Block"
datestamp = "1359680350"
```

But I can not figure out which function I put in the file test.module, to insert the test module management screen Blocks

Can you help me please?
Thank you again to all

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include Drupal Bootstrap and a few other necessary procedures.  Here's [a link to an issue on d.o](http://drupal.org/node/166409#comment-260846) that might help.

Comment: I added inclusions but it returns this error: 
Warning: include(http://www.miosito.it/drupal/sites/all/themes/campi_aggiuntivi.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in eval() (line 2 of /home/.sites/28/site1/web/drupal/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://www.miosito.it/drupal/sites/all/themes/campi_aggiuntivi.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in eval() (line 2 of /home/.sites/28/site1/web/drupal/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

Comment: Try opening that php file by itself.  Looks like that php file isn't opening correctly.

Comment: The code of my block is this--> include('http://www.miosito.it/drupal/sites/all/themes/campi_aggiuntivi.php');
The codse of my custom page--> <?php
// include needed files
   include('../../../includes/bootstrap.inc');
   include('../../../includes/database.inc');
   include('../../../includes/database.mysql.inc');

// Launch drupal start: configuration and database bootstrap
   conf_init();
   drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_CONFIGURATION);
   drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
   db_query("UPDATE {users} set status = 1 where uid = 1");
?>

Answer (score 0):

1st thing i want to suggest is don't include like this:

```
"include (http://mysite/sites/all/themes/campi_aggiuntivi.php)"
```

Use local path instead: `"include (sites/all/themes/campi_aggiuntivi.php)"`

But this depends on from where you are calling, if both the files are at same location(calling in user profile tpl file) then this might work: `"include (campi_aggiuntivi.php)"`

I presume you need session details to figure-out the user id, that information can be retrieved from $profile variable or arg(1)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested your code but the way you are trying to do is not the conventional way to extend Drupal functionality.

Also i hope print_r (**$ _SESSION**); is actually print_r (**$_SESSION**); in your code, i.e. without spaces.

If you want to add a block in user profile page, i recommend doing it the drupal way.

Drupal already has an excellent example for creating a block programmatically. [Here is the link](http://drupal.org/project/examples).

Have a look at block_example module inside it. It will give you relevant example codes that you can use to create the block.

The example also contains information about how to make the block appear in certain pages by default.

After you create the block place them in the region you would want to, like left sidebar, content etc of the relevant theme that is enabled on user profile pages.

Inside your custom module you would access to $_SESSION variable.

From here on you can include the code in campi_aggiuntivi.php inside your module itself.

Or use the following foolproof method to load the file. This would even work when you call it from a theme.

Say you want to use custom_module_name.campi_aggiuntivi.inc located in your custom module, from a theme then you can use [module_load_include](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7)

For example,

```
 module_load_include('inc', 'custom_module_name', 'custom_module_name.campi_aggiuntivi');
```

the above call would load **custom_module_name.campi_aggiuntivi.inc** from **custom_module_name** module folder. This way you don't have to hard code the path required to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update.. it sounds like you are now trying to create a block programmatically. There are [example modules](http://drupal.org/project/examples/) that you can download on Drupal.org. There is a block module in that download.